# Calling javascript when a partial view is loaded

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. In the application, I have a page with a button on it. When I click on the button a partial view is rendered in a window (see below). Inside the view I have a combo box and I need to load the combo box after the view is rendered. I tried to call the js right after win.show() but that doesn't work because the textbox used to render combo is inside the partial view. When should I call the js? Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
var win;
if (!win) {
    win = new Ext.Window({
        layout: 'fit',
        width: 750,
        height: 630,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        plain: true,
        autoLoad: {
            url: '../SearchJob/SearchPanel'
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () { }
        }, {
            text: 'Close Me',
            handler: function () {
                win.hide();
            }
        }]
    });
}
win.show(this);

}
```

Comment: Get yourself immersed in understanding events, especially in EXT JS.  Javascript is an event-driven language, and one can only perform actions after an event has been fired.  These events are fired after some display elements have been rendered, if you attempt to access this component before it is rendered, you will have null objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might add the < script > tag to the end of the partial view.  That way the script will not be parsed/executed until the partial view is completely rendered.

Comment: It worked now. I had to make this change: autoLoad: {
                url: '../SearchJob/SearchPanel',
                scripts: true
            }, Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the afterrender event on Ext.Window?

Comment: Yes you can use the after render event but the after render is fired too early. The after render event does not wait for the child comonent to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using autoLoad to load the partial view contents, you have to wait until the window has received the response with the partial view contents and has been updated with the components/markup... so you can listen for the `update` event of the window's updater...

```
win.on('render', function(component) {
    win.getUpdater().on('update', function(el, response) {
            // Load Combo
    }, win, {single:true});
});
```

[EDIT]
Make sure you set the event handler to run only once though... edits are above

```
var win;
if (!win) {
    win = new Ext.Window({
        layout: 'fit',
        width: 750,
        height: 630,
        closeAction: 'hide',
        plain: true,
        autoLoad: {
            url: '../SearchJob/SearchPanel'
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function () { }
        }, {
            text: 'Close Me',
            handler: function () {
                win.hide();
            }
        }]
    });    
    win.on('render', function(component) {
        win.getUpdater().on('update', function(el, response) {
                // Load Combo
        }, win, {single:true});
    });
}
win.show(this);
```

Comment: I coundn't get this to working. I am still new to EXTJS, if you can please tell me where to put this code that will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just put it right after the definition of `win` -- see update above

Comment: Sorry, you have to wait until the window is rendered to add a listener for the updater `update` event -- the correct code is shown above now